# PRODUCT array formula containing INDIRECT not working

Tags: arrays, excel

Can anybody see why this array formula isn't working?:

`{=PRODUCT(IF(INDIRECT(F7)=1,INDIRECT(AM7)))}`

NB: the cells to which the cell references refer each contain ranges, e.g. $E$3:$E$6 is in F7.

And these range reference strings have been generated by, for example:
`=ADDRESS(K7,MATCH("N",$5:$5,0))&":"&ADDRESS(L7,MATCH("N",$5:$5,0))`

For the avoidance of doubt, 3 is in K7 and 5 is in L7.

Cheers

Comment: P.S. I should have said that a 1 (i.e. the false argument in the IF statement) is returned in every cell covered by the array formula

Comment: Apologies, 1 isn't the false argument in the IF statement; I don't know what it is.

Comment: On a test workbook, the formula works as expected for me.  Can you please provide some sample data showing what the expected result is and what you're getting instead?